# Why is it called "expression body" in kotlin? fun max(a: Int, b: Int): Int = if

Tags: kotlin

I saw a tutorial says that this function

```
fun max(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
    return if (a < b) a else b
}
```

can be converted into **expression body**

```
fun max(a: Int, b: Int): Int = if (a < b) a else b
```

I know there are statement, expression, and block concepts in Java.

But I didn't have idea what does **expression body** actually mean..?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Function normally has a body, enclosed by `{` `}`. When your function body is just a single expression, then it is said that function has an expression body. **Expression body** is not a special phrase, but rather just means **the function body which is an expression**.